# How to determine size of c_uint at build.rs time for the target platform not host platform?

Tags: rust

During `build.rs` time, I'm generating Rust code that calls a C function with a variable number of arguments:

```
//build.rs
fn generate_code(param_name: &str, param_type: &str);
```

This generates:

```
c_func(x, {param_name});
```

where `param_type` is any integer type.

The problem is with "integer promotions". For example, this code gives a compile-time error because `p` should be promoted to a `c_uint` by the C calling conventions for variadics and Rust does not do it implicitly:

```
use std::os::raw::c_uint;

extern "C" {
    fn c_func(x: c_uint, ...);
}

fn main() {
    let x: c_uint = 1;
    let p: u8 = 2;
    c_func(x, p);
}
```

To promote the integer, I need to know the size of `c_uint` on the target platform to convert integer types with size <= `c_uint` to `c_uint` (and signed types to `c_int`),

Maybe there is some kind of trick I can do with the help of generated code (
like `c_func(x, p.promote());`), where the `promote` function is part of some magic `trait` that promotes to the suitable type?

Comment: Why not just do `c_func(x, p as c_uint)` ?

Comment: @Shepmaster because of size of p may be bigger that `c_uint` in this case I not need this conversation, and actually this conversation create bug in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there's any way of accessing that information in the build script.

> where the `promote` function is part of some magic trait that promotes to the suitable type?

That sounds like a workable solution. You can implement this trait for various types depending on the target platform:

```
extern crate libc;

trait Promote {
    type Output;

    fn promote(self) -> Self::Output;
}

// This can be made into a macro for all the "easy" cases
impl Promote for u8 {
    type Output = libc::c_uint;

    fn promote(self) -> Self::Output {
        self as Self::Output
    }
}

#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "32")]
impl Promote for u64 {
    type Output = libc::uint64_t;

    fn promote(self) -> Self::Output {
        self as Self::Output
    }
}

#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]
impl Promote for u64 {
    type Output = libc::c_uint;

    fn promote(self) -> Self::Output {
        self as Self::Output
    }
}

extern "C" {
    fn foo(a: u8, ...);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        foo(1, 1u8.promote(), 1u64.promote());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem that I know nothing about `unsigned int` or `c_uint`, C standard says  nothing about it, like at least `2^16` values and that's all. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models your code with `#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]` `for u64` may truncate result removing high 32 bit value or work in right way.